# Why server didn't see the clients sending data?

Tags: java, serversocket

Why  on the serverSocket.accept() happens nothing ? Server get a data from client, but programm do nothing on the method serverSocket.accept()

```
public void start() {
        try {
            Socket socket= serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client accepted");

            in = new DataInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
                    try {
                    line = in.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(line);

                } catch (IOException i) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
serverSocket.accept();
```

blocks until a socket is connected.

```
Socket s = serverSocket.accept();

in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
```

OR

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

**EDIT - 29.03.2019 11.54**

So we know:

```
serverSocket.accept();
```

blocks your thread. You call it in your main thread.

```
...
successfulThreads = new AtomicInteger(0);
latch = new CountDownLatch(testcaseThreads);
gate = new CyclicBarrier(testcaseThreads + 1);

server = new Server(SOCKET_PORT);
server.start();  //<-- Your program blocks!!!
//  ||
//  || STOP! No execution of the code.
// \\//
//  \/
for (File testcaseFile : testcaseFiles) {
            new Thread(new MockClient(this, testcaseFile)).start();
}
```

Comment: and nothing changed :(